# How to prevent phpunit from changing the array structure in dataprovider?

Tags: php, phpunit

This is what I have in the data provider

```
'username' => [
    'requried'  => true,
    'min'       => 3,
    'max'       => 16,
]
```

and I want this to stay in the same form, but phpunit translates it to

```
[
    "requried" => true,
    "min" => 3,
    "max"=> 16,
]
```

Now how to prevent this? I need to perform an assert, but because phpunit converts it like this, it's actually not doable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems your data is interpreted as as name of the datasets so the first key is ignored. Check the example 2.6 in the [doc section](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers)

Try with something like:

```
'first scenario' => [ 
   'username' => [
     'requried'  => true,
     'min'       => 3,
     'max'       => 16,
   ]
]
```

Hope this help

PS: Probably a typo with `requried` instead of required

Comment: Thanks for the hint! It actually was only the typo.